# Fail to sync data to hadoop cluster (Failed to place enough replicas)

Tags: hadoop

I installed the Hadoop cluster in ubuntu 20.04. After the Hadoop cluster is installed, I was faced with a big issue. The pipeline of Data sync from the client to the Hadoop cluster is broken.  The data I intend to transfer to the Hadoop cluster is about 18Gb. Although my DFS remaining is 65%, the pipeline transfer file from the client to the Hadoop cluster failed. I tried to format nameNode and dataNode but the result still failed.
Someone can help me fix that?
These are some pieces of information for us:

**Log failed:**

```
2022-06-09 10:46:08,507 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: Not enough replicas was chosen. Reason: {NOT_ENOUGH_STORAGE_SPACE=3, NO_REQUIRED_STORAGE_TYPE=1}
2022-06-09 10:46:08,507 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: Not enough replicas was chosen. Reason: {NO_REQUIRED_STORAGE_TYPE=1}
2022-06-09 10:46:08,508 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: Failed to place enough replicas, still in need of 3 to reach 3 (unavailableStorages=[], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}, newBlock=true) For more information, please enable DEBUG log level on org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy and org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology
2022-06-09 10:46:08,508 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.BlockStoragePolicy: Failed to place enough replicas: expected size is 3 but only 0 storage types can be selected (replication=3, selected=[], unavailable=[DISK], removed=[DISK, DISK, DISK], policy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]})
2022-06-09 10:46:08,508 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: Failed to place enough replicas, still in need of 3 to reach 3 (unavailableStorages=[DISK], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}, newBlock=true) All required storage types are unavailable:  unavailableStorages=[DISK], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}
2022-06-09 10:46:08,511 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 8 on default port 9000, call Call#1744126 Retry#0 org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from 172.24.217.203:38560
java.io.IOException: File /.reserved/.inodes/30284/.9DFE31A1-742F11EC-981DADC9-CEAF568F@172.24.219.148.wav.C5j1SD could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2960)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:904)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1043)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:971)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2976)
```

**My DFS admin report:**

```
Name: 172.24.217.204:9866 (hadoop-node1)
Hostname: hadoop-node1
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 104091082752 (96.94 GB)
DFS Used: 19833880576 (18.47 GB)
Non DFS Used: 11562889216 (10.77 GB)
DFS Remaining: 67362725888 (62.74 GB)
DFS Used%: 19.05%
DFS Remaining%: 64.72%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 0
Last contact: Thu Jun 09 11:26:29 ICT 2022
Last Block Report: Thu Jun 09 09:54:17 ICT 2022
Num of Blocks: 9033


Name: 172.24.217.205:9866 (hadoop-node2)
Hostname: hadoop-node2
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 104091082752 (96.94 GB)
DFS Used: 19833790464 (18.47 GB)
Non DFS Used: 11416346624 (10.63 GB)
DFS Remaining: 67509358592 (62.87 GB)
DFS Used%: 19.05%
DFS Remaining%: 64.86%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 0
Last contact: Thu Jun 09 11:26:29 ICT 2022
Last Block Report: Thu Jun 09 10:02:23 ICT 2022
Num of Blocks: 9033


Name: 172.24.217.206:9866 (hadoop-node3)
Hostname: hadoop-node3
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 104091082752 (96.94 GB)
DFS Used: 19833802752 (18.47 GB)
Non DFS Used: 10835709952 (10.09 GB)
DFS Remaining: 68089982976 (63.41 GB)
DFS Used%: 19.05%
DFS Remaining%: 65.41%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 0
Last contact: Thu Jun 09 11:26:29 ICT 2022
Last Block Report: Thu Jun 09 09:54:17 ICT 2022
Num of Blocks: 9033
```

**My core-site.xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:9000</value>
    </property>

<!-->HTTP/dfs proxy-->  
   <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**My hdfs-site.xml config:**

```
 *<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/opt/hadoop/dfsdata/nameNode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>[DISK]file:///opt/hadoop/dfsdata/dataNode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.redundancy.considerLoad</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    
    <!-- HDFS NFS gateway -->
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.accesstime.precision</name>
        <value>3600000</value>
        <description>
    The access time for HDFS file is precise up to this value. 
    The default value is 1 hour. Setting a value of 0 disables
    access times for HDFS.
  </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.storage.policy.enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.nfs3.dump.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp/.hdfs-nfs</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.nfs.exports.allowed.hosts</name>
        <value>172.24.217.0/24 rw ; 172.30.12.0/24 rw ; 172.24.216.0/24 rw</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>nfs.export.point</name>
        <value>/</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.redundancy.considerLoad.factor</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </property>
</configuration>*
```

Answer (score 0):

I used three dev virtual machines to deploy a hadoop cluster and encountered a similar problem to yours.

I opened the log and set the debug level org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology according to the prompts.

```
2022-08-31 10:43:32,576 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: Choosing random from 2 available nodes on node /default-rack, scope=/default-rack, excludedScope=null, excludeNodes=[]. numOfDatanodes=2.
2022-08-31 10:43:32,576 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: chooseRandom returning x.x.x.x:9866
2022-08-31 10:43:32,577 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: Failed to find datanode (scope="" excludedScope="/default-rack"). numOfDatanodes=0
2022-08-31 10:43:32,577 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology: No node to choose.
```

I suspect it is a network problem. I went to the machine to telnet the port 9866, and it really didn't work. Then I opened this port. After opening this port, my hadoop problem was solved.

I hope it will be useful to you.